# How can I ask for a new dhcp lease on windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, dhcp

In windows7 how do I request a new dhcp lease ?

What I need in the equivalent of the button "repair" on windows XP. The button "diagnose" seems to do a few things but not request a new dhcp lease if one is already available.

Disabling and re-enabling the card does the trick but messes up any program capturing traffic on the interface.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question is a little confusing. Do you want to renew the current lease or acquire a new address? If you want to renew the current lease, from a command prompt type:

ipconfig/renew

Comment: Glad to help...